# why the position:relative does not work as I expected with float

Tags: css, css-float

This is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/XnWsg/),

Note the  `.mappanel`,it take cover all the width of the browser,while I want the `.textview` div display at the right.

When I remove the position:relative,it worked(while I can not remove the `position:relative` for both.

In fact,what I want is the `.textview` take a fixed width (380 in my example),and the `.mappanel` take the left.

And at some point,the `.textview` can collapsed,then the `.mappanel` take all the width

---

Update:

Some one suggest me use the `z-index`,however I can not.

Because if I use the `z-index`,and the `.textview` appear. But the `.mappanel` also take the whole width of the parent,while I just it want it take the lefe space.

That' to say,if the parent div of the two elements have a width:600px,and then the `.mappanel` will have (600-380)px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `z-index` issue. Your `.textview` panel is appearing underneath your `.mappanel`. This is because you have defined a `position` for them, which will give them a default `z-index`. And because the `.mappanel` comes after the `.textview` in the code, it will appear above.

Try this:

**CSS**

```css
.textview {
    width: 380px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0px;
    float:right;
    height: 535px;
    background: #cc0000;
}
.mappanel {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 0;
    background: #0000cc;
    height: 535px;
    margin-right: 380px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XnWsg/4/)**

**Update 1**

To fix the width of the non-float panel to not go under the floated panel you can add margin to the right side of it:

```
    margin-right: 380px;
```

I've updated the demo above if you would like to see it running.

Comment: @hguser - I've added to my answer in reply to this. Have a look